# RabbitMQ not starting automatically after installation

Tags: linux, rabbitmq

RabbitMQ does not start automatically after installation on my system.

Tried checking the status by running the following line of code

```
sudo rabbitmqctl status
```

output: "The handle is invalid"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's operation system do you use?

usually you need to enable autostart by executing command

```
sudo systemctl enable rabbitmq-server
```